# How to get Multiple row from a single row database table from PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, unpivot

I have a PostgreSQL Database table name Intime

| Name | Intime1 | Intime2 | Intime3 | Intime4 | Intime5 | Intime6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zakir |  | 02/01/18:9.00 |  | 04/01/18:9.07 |  | 06/01/18:9.05 |

I want from this table:

| Name | Intime |
| --- | --- |
| Zakir | 02/01/18:9.00 |
| Zakir | 04/01/18:9.07 |
| Zakir | 06/01/18:9.05 |

Now what is the query in the PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UNION:

```
select name, intime1 as intime
from intime
union all
select name, intime2
from intime
union all
select name, intime3
from intime
union all
select name, intime4
from intime
union all
select name, intime5
from intime
union all
select name, intime6
from intime
```

Another - Postgres specific - solution would be to use `unnest` on an array of the columns:

```
select i.name, t.intime
from intime as i
  cross join unnest(array[intime1,intime2,intime3,intime4,intime5,intime6]) as t(intime);
```

If you also want to know which column each row belongs to, you can use `with ordinality`:

```
select i.name, t.intime, t.nr
from intime as i
  cross join unnest(array[intime1,intime2,intime3,intime4,intime5,intime6]) with ordinality as t(intime,nr);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/CDHVI81806

Comment: Dear "a_horse_with_no_name" Your 2nd query does not work. Do you check it again please. Thank u for 1st one.

Comment: @ZakirHossain: sorry, there was a typo `(` instead of `[`

Answer (score 2):

Use a lateral join:

```
select t.name, v.intime
from t cross join lateral
      (values (intime1), (intime2), (intime3), (intime4), (intime5), (intime6)
      ) v(intime);
```

Lateral joins are ANSI/ISO standard syntax that can be quite powerful.  Unpivoting data is just one thing that can be done with them.